# ICS extension as PHP with Apache2

Tags: php, apache, icalendar

I am trying to serve up an ics (ical) file via a url. Accessing my "ical.php" is fine. But many apps insist the url has a .ics extension. If I symlink "shamrock.ics" to ical.php then the raw php file is served up. I found a rewrite rule elsewhere in stackoverflow (RewriteRule ^(.*).ics$ $1.php [QSA]) but this doesnt work for me (other rewrites I use do work so I know the rewrite engine works).

Can someone suggest the next step or the best path to take to solve this.

Comment: can you post your other rules too maybe something conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. And its not using rewrites. Simply add "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .html .htm .ics" to the httpd.conf. I should have found that.